# Sass: Create mixin for input fields

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm new to Sass so I need help with the creation of a mixing for my input fields.

However, if anyone knows of an already made mixin for this or if Compass has one that accomplishes this, please let me (us) know.

I currently have the following CSS rules in my .scss file:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="url"],
textarea, 
select { ... }

input[type="text"]:hover,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:hover,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:hover,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:hover,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:hover,
input[type="url"]:focus,
textarea:hover,
textarea:focus,
select:hover,
select:focus  { ... }
```

Now, as we know HTML5 provides a nice new set of [input types](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201004/html5_input_types/), but right now I don't need to add input types like `date`, `month` or `week`, that's why I don't have them listed "yet".

So in the case I need to add them in the future, I'll update that list you see above.

However, my problem is that I feel I'm repeating myself all over here, plus, the work of selecting items, copying, pasting and editing every time for every new input type I add to the list is just plain dumb and I almost sure Sass' mixins can be of help with this. The problem is that creating a mixin for this is honestly very confusing to me.

I've looked around here and the web for something similar but haven't been able to find anything.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to list these types when in the end they all get the same style? a plain `input{}` would do the same in this case...

Comment: @Christoph if you notice, only texty type fields have been listed (omitting date, color, range, number, etc.).  Certain non-texty elements end up looking funny if you try to apply certain styles to them, similar to the file input element.

Comment: Cinnamon is correct. Also, buttons are also `inputs` and I don't want to 'negate' their properties somewhere else because of using such a general rule. I found a solution, read below (posting right now).

Comment: You can't solve that with mixins, at it's best you could use variable interpolation.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, I'm not a programmer, but seems that that's what the original mixin does, so I just repeated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I eventually found the Sass mixing library **[Bourbon](http://thoughtbot.github.com/bourbon/)**.

They have an 'add-on' for [HTML5 input types](http://thoughtbot.github.com/bourbon/#html5-input-types) (here's a [link to the .scss file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/addons/_html5-input-types.scss) they created), but it doesn't have the `:hover` or `:focus` pseudo elements. So I added them.

I honestly don't know if what I did is the best way to write this mixin, but the thing works marvelously:

```
//************************************************************************//
// Generate a variable ($all-text-inputs) with a list of all html5
// input types that have a text-based input, excluding textarea.
// http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html
//************************************************************************//
$inputs-list: 'input[type="email"]',
              'input[type="number"]',
              'input[type="password"]',
              'input[type="search"]',
              'input[type="tel"]',
              'input[type="text"]',
              'input[type="url"]',

              // Webkit & Gecko may change the display of these in the future
              'input[type="color"]',
              'input[type="date"]',
              'input[type="datetime"]',
              'input[type="datetime-local"]',
              'input[type="month"]',
              'input[type="time"]',
              'input[type="week"]';

$unquoted-inputs-list: ();

@each $input-type in $inputs-list {
  $unquoted-inputs-list: append($unquoted-inputs-list, unquote($input-type), comma);
}

$all-text-inputs: $unquoted-inputs-list;

// You must use interpolation on the variable:
// #{$all-text-inputs}
//************************************************************************//
//   #{$all-text-inputs}, textarea {
//     border: 1px solid red;
//   }

// :hover and :focus pseudo elements
// Added by Ricardo Zea
// http://ricardozea.net
// @ricardozea
// Tracking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180807/sass-create-mixin-for-input-fields

$inputs-list-hf:'input[type="email"]:hover',
                'input[type="number"]:hover',
                'input[type="password"]:hover',
                'input[type="search"]:hover',
                'input[type="tel"]:hover',
                'input[type="text"]:hover',
                'input[type="url"]:hover',
                'input[type="color"]:hover',
                'input[type="date"]:hover',
                'input[type="datetime"]:hover',
                'input[type="datetime-local"]:hover',
                'input[type="month"]:hover',
                'input[type="time"]:hover',
                'input[type="week"]:hover',

                'input[type="email"]:focus',
                'input[type="number"]:focus',
                'input[type="password"]:focus',
                'input[type="search"]:focus',
                'input[type="tel"]:focus',
                'input[type="text"]:focus',
                'input[type="url"]:focus',
                'input[type="color"]:focus',
                'input[type="date"]:focus',
                'input[type="datetime"]:focus',
                'input[type="datetime-local"]:focus',
                'input[type="month"]:focus',
                'input[type="time"]:focus',
                'input[type="week"]:focus';

$unquoted-inputs-list-hf: ();

@each $input-type-hf in $inputs-list-hf {
  $unquoted-inputs-list-hf: append($unquoted-inputs-list-hf, unquote($input-type-hf), comma);
}

$all-text-inputs-hf: $unquoted-inputs-list-hf;

// You must use interpolation on the variable:
// #{$all-text-inputs-hf}
//************************************************************************//
//   #{$all-text-inputs-hf}, textarea {
//     border: 1px solid red;
//   }
```

As you can see I copied and pasted the original mixing and added the prefix `-hf` and of course the `:hover` and `:focus` to the new rules.

And in my .scss file I added this *@import*:

`@import "html5-input-types";` (no need for the underline `_` or file extension `.scss`)

And in the 'Forms' section of my .scss file I added these rules:

```
/*Normal state*/
#{$all-text-inputs}, 
textarea,
select { ... }

/*:hover and :focus states*/
#{$all-text-inputs-hf}, 
textarea:hover, 
textarea:focus,
select:hover,
select:focus { ... }
```

I know I have `textarea` and `select` outside the mixin file (*html5-input-types.scss*), not sure yet if I'm including them in it or not, gotta think about it.

Anyway, this worked for me pretty well and although I will still need to update the *html5-input-types.scss* if anything changes in the future, at least I'm handling these input fields way more efficiently than before.

Hopefully what I did here helps someone else.

And if any of you has a suggestion to improve the mixin, by all means let me (us) know.

Thanks.

Comment: well, as i said, you can only use interpolated variables. Since I think you are only using one rule for your inputs and one for the hover/focus you ended up with significant overhead - not worth it imo. (It would make sense, if you used this lists over and over again). This only slows down the SASS-parsing...

Comment: `#{$all-text-inputs}, textarea, select { ... &:hover, &:focus { ... } }` saves some typing.

Comment: @Christoph The parsing is done by my computer, not by me or the server so no hurt there. Also, I can use this file over and over with other projects without having to copy and paste the entire block of rules to each .scss file. As I said, if you have a better way of doing it, great, share with everyone. Coming up with this on my own was great because I learned a bit more about SASS and mixins, and well, 'interpolated variables'. Thanks.

Comment: @cimmanon Doh! You're right, hehe. But the above solution works even better. Gave you an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried this with Yeoman and this does not work. Does someone know a workaround for Yeoman?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this for the same reason I did. Why not let SASS do the work?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cschloegel/pen/dybXGwg?editors=1100#0)

```
$form-background: #f8f8f8;
$form-color: #000;
$form-border: 1px solid lighten($form-color, 50%);

$form-focus-background: darken($form-background, 10%);
$form-focus-color: #999;
$form-focus-border: 1px solid $form-color;

%input-styles {
    width: 15em;
    min-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    background: $form-background;
    color: $form-color;
    border: $form-border;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    transition-property: color, background-color, border;
}

%input-styles--focus {
    background-color: $form-focus-background;
    color: $form-focus-color;
    border: $form-focus-border;
}

@mixin input-styles($styles, $focus_styles) {
    $types: 'email', 'number', 'radio', 'password', 'search', 'tel',
            'text', 'url', 'color', 'date', 'datetime',
            'datetime-local', 'month', 'time', 'week';

    @each $type in $types {
        input[type="#{$type}"] {
            @extend #{$styles};

            &:focus {
                @extend #{$focus_styles};
            }
        }
    }

    select,
    textarea {
        @extend #{$styles};

        &:focus {
            @extend #{$focus_styles};
        }
    }
}

@include input-styles('%input-styles', '%input-styles--focus');
```

Comment: Not that I can't create it, but adding a working demo to your answer would be a HUGE help for others. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Added a CodePen, @RicardoZea

Comment: Awesome! Massive improvement on your answer. Gave you an upvote, and a Like on CodePen as well :). Thank you!