# Wildcard selector for each input type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to know, if there is any wildcard selector for an `input[type=""]`.

Something like `input[type="*"]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCSS/CSS selector to select all input types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085053/scss-css-selector-to-select-all-input-types)

Comment: see line item 3 here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, without value

```
 input[type] {

 }
```

It targets all inputs that has a `type` attribute with or without value.

Answer (score 0):

You can target all the input types with:

```
input[type]{

}
```

For more details: [Link to answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085053/scss-css-selector-to-select-all-input-types)

Comment: In future, if you've found a duplicate question, flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting an answer linking to the other question.