# Is there a succint way to select all HTML form input elements without repeating rule selectors?

Tags: html, css

HTML has a design problem, in my opinion, whereby form input elements are inconsistently a `type` of `<input />` (`checkbox`, `text`, etc) or are their own element type (`select`, `textarea`, etc). I understand it's based on the element's needs for child elements or not (`<select>` and `<textarea>` have children, but `<input />` does not) but the different types of `<input />` result in wildly different rendering - for example, `checkbox` and `radio` generally render as a small clickable square-shared input, whereas `text` and `password` are rectangular with no prescribed width.

This means that if you're styling inputs, you will *need* multiple rules.

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Option 2
    </label>
</div>

<div class="field">
    A question?
    <label>
        <input type="radio" /> Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" /> Option 2
    </label>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>
        Your name
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>
        An essay
        <textarea></textarea>
    </label>
</div>
```

If you want to style only text inputs, you might think you would only need:

```
input,
textarea {
    border: 1px inset green;
}
```

However this will also (inappropriately) style the `radio` and `checkbox` inputs, so you either need to style `input` and then add a new rule for `input[type=radio]` and `input[type=checkbox]` that either re-styles them to match your design or resets their style - or change the rule to match `input[type=text]`.

But neither is perfect, because the input rule still doesn't specify a style for the other types of `input`: either those modelled after a textbox (e.g. `password` and `email`) or those that are not (`color`, `image`, `file`, etc). You will need to add a rule for each and every type that you believe you could need - in addition to all of the other form elements, like `select`, `textarea`, `button`, and so on - and then you will need to repeat these selectors for each case the style needs to be different in a new context:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=password],
input[type=search],
input[type=tel],
input[type=url],
input[type=email],
textarea {
    border: 1px inset green;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
    border: none;
}

.someWrapper input[type=text],
.someWrapper input[type=password],
.someWrapper input[type=search],
.someWrapper input[type=tel],
.someWrapper input[type=url],
.someWrapper input[type=email],
.someWrapper textarea {
    border: 1px inset green;
}

.someWrapper input[type=radio],
.someWrapper input[type=checkbox] {
    border: none;
}

/* etc */
```

However I feel many inputs can be grouped into "input classes", such as the "text input" class: `text`, `password`, `textarea`, `email`, `search`, etc - the "box input" class: `checkbox`, `radio`, the "date" class: `date`, `datetime`, `month`, etc, and so on.

So rather than manually adding these classes as `class` values to my inputs in HTML, is there any browser-intrinsic way, such as through a CSS pseudo-class, e.g. `input:textbox` or `input:boxinput`? If so, this would greatly simplify CSS selectors for forms and reduce CSS bugs from missing selectors.

Comment: The "date" class you listed would be part of the "text input" class. Browsers that support them add extra UI, but base it on a standard text input field. Also browsers that don't support the new HTML5 input types will render all of them as a default text box. But no, there is no generic "text-box-type input field" selector in CSS.

Comment: Why would you even need a wrapper? Couldn't you create just a form field class where all user inputs have the class `form-field`?

Comment: @Adjit Yes, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without changing my HTML to add extra `class` attribute values.

Comment: Have you tried just plain `input[type]`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699030/wildcard-selector-for-each-input-type

Comment: @Adjit Given that `type` is a required attribute on `<input />` then the rules `input` and `input[type]` are equivalent (unless you're styling invalid HTML). And that doesn't help differentiating between `<input type="checkbox" />` and `<input type="email" />`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, there is something in CSS that *nearly* does what you want. The `:read-write` psuedo-selector (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-write) selects elements that are editable by the user.

Consider the following:

```
<input type="radio" selected /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" selected><br>
<input type="button" value="Click me"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit me"><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<input type="password"><br>
<input type="email"><br>
<input type="date"><br>
<textarea></textarea><br>
```

The bottom 5 elements (not counting `br`s) will be selected and highlighted with the following one line of CSS:

```
*:read-write {border:1px solid #f3f;}
```

Browser support is fairly good for basic form fields.

Note: I say *nearly* in the first line. This selects date fields.

Comment: The down side (or up side) with this, it will also target any _editable_ element other than i.e. `input`, such as a `div` with the `contenteditable` attribute

Comment: @LGSon Fortunately those elements can be first matched and excluded with `*:read-write:not(input)` - or the inverse: `input:read-write` (with an exception for `textarea`).

Comment: @Dai I am well aware of that :) ... my comment were to simply shed some light on the posted answer, and I can't say why I didn't add that in my comment, so thanks...comment upvoted

Comment: @Dai Btw, won't this be an option `input:not([type=radio]):not([type=checkbox]) {}` ... I made an answer with that though I see I deleted it, and can't really say why

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `input[type]` however, that does not necessarily help you when applying to `select` or `textarea` fields. But you would have to add those selectors regardless.

```css
input[type],
textarea {
    border: 1px inset green;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
    border: none;
}

input[type],
textarea {
    border: 1px inset green;
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="click"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox"/><br/>
<input type="radio"/><br/>
<input type="color"/><br/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: `input[type]` is moot as **all** `<input />` elements have the `type=""` attribute defined (excluding invalid documents, of course).